# What is the general name for someone who does fraud

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, american-english, british-english

What is someone who does fraud called?

- I tried to look in the dictionary with words like 'frauder' and similar things but did get any results.
- I tried google with searches like 'What is someone that does fraud called' or just 'fraud', but I only found articles on identity fraud.

Comment: The answer to the question was quite obvious. The question also indicates that you have not done any research to find out the answer. Ideally you are expected to elaborate/ justify as to what research efforts you had made previously regarding your question.

Comment: Dear @Monzoor, First off all the answer to this question was not quite obvious unless you are a native English speaker. I tried to look it up in the dictionery with words like 'frauder' and similar things but did get any results. I searched google with questions like 'What is someone that does fraud called' and did not find the result. Do not rush to JUDGE people!

Comment: Try typing "fraud" into google, and see what suggested searches it comes up with.

Comment: This should help in future searches: [Google "person who * fraud"](https://www.google.co.in/search?&q="person+who+*+fraud")

Comment: @AndyT I searched what you said and ended up with articles about how to avoid identity-fraud and articles in history of online frauds and so on, but not the word 'fraudster'! May be because I live in a different country, I see different results in the page. But anyway, a few people liked the answer & comments below the nswer. That means it was helpfull for a few people including me. That's what we are all here for.

Comment: @Mori - Suggested searches, not articles. As in, you start typing in "what does a " and google suggests auto-complete such as "what does a cpu do" and "what does a cell wall do". When I type in "fraud", the 4th option google suggests is "fraudster". I agree that maybe you might see different results from different countries.

Comment: @AndyT That only works if you already know that _fraudster_ is what you’re looking for. If you don’t know that word, seeing it on a list (which also includes words like _fraudulence_, _fraude_, and _fraudbuster_) won’t be of much help.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - If you see a word, that you don't know what it means, when you're looking for a word that has the same root, I'd suggest looking up the word you found in a dictionary!

Comment: I have reopened this question, since the original poster had trouble finding the answer with obvious Google searches. FWIW, I find all the suggestions of how the poster *could* have found the answer with carefully constructed use of Google to be exactly besides the point.

Comment: FWIW, one doesn't "do" fraud—one "commits" fraud.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **fraudster**
>   *chiefly British*
>   a person who engages in fraud
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fraudster

Note that while several dictionaries tag this as "chiefly British",  the Wikipedia article about the *American* financier Bernard Madoff does call him a *fraudster*.

---

There's also a **swindler**:

> **swindle**
>   to obtain money or property by fraud or deceit
>   https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/swindler

Comment: My day job is working in fraud detection and prevention and I can confirm we call our quarry "fraudsters"

Comment: I see this term in American English a lot too, so the "chiefly British" shoujld indeed be taken with a grain of salt.  Also simply "a fraud", though I suppose the connotation is slightly different (a person whose identity is fraudulent, rather than who merely engages in some sort of fraud, perhaps?)

Comment: @tripleee A fraud is not necessarily someone who commits fraud _strictu sensu_ (“deceit, trickery, sharp practice, or breach of confidence, perpetrated for profit or to gain some unfair or dishonest advantage”); it can just be someone who gives the impression (implicit or explicit) that they are more than what they really are. It's someone who “makes deceitful pretenses; a sham; a poseur”. (ODO)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yeah, thanks, that's what I was getting at.

Comment: I'd also add "scammer" to this list, again with slightly different connotations.

Comment: @tripleee *scammer* is informal. I understood the question as asking for a formal term.

Comment: _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ (2003) lists 1960 as the year of first recorded occurrence for _fraudster_; the word doesn't appear in the _Tenth Collegiate_ (1993) or any prior edition of the Collegiate series. In my opinion, the "chiefly British" designation was iffy in 2003 and is incorrect now. At the U.S. tech magazines where I worked from 1995 to 2014, we used _fraudster_ and _scammer_ almost interchangeably as terms for people who engaged in fraudulent schemes on the Internet. I think _fraudster_ is now common and standard in the U.S., in part because of such usage.

Answer (score 1):

**defrauder**

My understanding is that fraud is a definition of a criminal behavior/method/act. A person can -commit- fraud, but if they use fraud against someone, they are 'defrauding' someone.

You don't 'fraud' someone, you 'defraud' them.

However, if people in the field commonly use the term "fraudster" it is easier on the tongue than the standard noun construction "defrauder" (my opinion would be to go with the other answer lol)

[merriam-webster's definition of defraud](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/defraud)

> Definition of defraud
>
> transitive verb
>
> :  to deprive of something by deception or fraud
>
> defrauder \di-ˈfrȯ-dər\ noun

Answer (score 0):

Another British term is [confidence trickster](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/confidence_trickster) which is similar to [con artist](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/con_artist) or [con man](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/con_man) which are more universal.

These terms are, however, slightly more specific than *fraudster* since they imply that the perpetrator has persuaded the victim to trust them through some form of personal contact whereas a *fraudster* may have exploited a weakness in a system (usually, but not exclusively, an IT system)

Another American term is [grifter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grift) which is similar to *fraudster* but usually refers only to small-scale fraud.